# Apache do not show index of directory

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, debian

How can I hide the contents of a directory without an index file from being displayed to the user i.e show "Index of:" ? For example, I have a folder called /documents with alot of subdirectories now inside of the subdirectories there will be files stored for example test.pdf. The full URL will look as follows www.example.com/documents/874256987/test.pdf. Currently if the user types www.example.com/documents into the url, all of the subdirectories are displayed, this is what I want to avoid. Only if the user knows the full url for example www.example.com/documents/874258726/test.pdf, the user is able to open the document in the browser. I have tried "IndexIgnore" inside of a .htaccess file, but the problem is even if the user knows the full url he/she will get 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by changing "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews" to "Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews" inside of my conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available. Removing "Indexes" did the trick. Now when someone types in www.example.com/documents they get 403 error, but providing the full path www.example.com/documents/850752485/test.pdf the file is displayed in the browser.

Comment: You could consider creating a default index file that redirects to the front page or gives a nice message and serve it up via rewrite rules or simply programmatically copy/link it to each directory